# Algorithm - Finding all of the connectors in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Definition: In an undirected graph, vertex v is a **connector** if there are at least two other vertices x and w for which every path between x and w goes through v.

I am using an adjacency linked list to store my graph.

So my first thought was "duh, well a vertex is a connector if it is the only neighbor to a vertex."

And although that works I realize now that there are other cases where a vertex is a connector even if it does not have that quality.

I have come up with a solution where I check every path of a vertex's neighbor to see if I can reach every other vertex and as you can probably imagine this will be VERY time consuming.

I've been trying to come up with a quicker algorithm but am unable to do so. Can anyone give me a hint for how I should go about solving this problem?

Comment: Sounds like the articulation point or cut vertex of a graph.

Comment: A node is not a connector if it is the only neighbor if the node does not have another neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your graph is connected. if you remove a connector vertex, the graph must be disconnected. Then, count number of component of a graph using dfs or bfs in linear time. If the number of component changed, it means the removed vertex or node is a connector.

You can run this algorithm for each vertex. Time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^2)`.